# Overlapping LabelBullet text in AmCharts 4

Tags: label, amcharts4

In Line Series, when bullets are close to each other, labels get overlapped, what is the optimal solution for this?

Here is a screenshot of the case;
[Overlapping bullet text in AmCharts 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qeaie.png)